# How to use `tmutil compare snapshot_path`?

Tags: terminal, time-machine, apfs

`man tmutil` shows

```
compare [-@acdefglmnstuEUX] [-D depth] [-I name] [snapshot_path | path1 path2]


If a snapshot path is provided as the sole argument, 
tmutil will compare the computer to the specified snapshot.
```

Does the 'snapshot' mean the result of `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` (APFS snapshot)?

I tried several ways but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 2):

From `man tmutil`:

```
snapshot
  A directory inside a machine directory that represents a single initial or
  incremental backup of one computer. The word "snapshot", in most contexts, is a
  generic term and is not to be confused with a "local Time Machine snapshot",
  which is simply a snapshot stored locally on the computer. E.g.,

    /Volumes/Chronoton/Backups.backupdb/thermopylae/2011-07-03-123456
```

I read this as "a local snapshot is not the same as a snapshot", with `tmutil compare` only able to handle the second.